# TronBox compile issue

Tags: smartcontracts, tron, tronbox

- I've installed the latest [tronbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tronbox) (2.7.5) using npm
- Created a new project using command `tronbox init`
- In file tronbox.js I've updated the compiler version to 0.4.25 (see the file below).
- When compiling using the command `tronbox compile --compile-all --reset` I'm getting:

Windows error:

[image]

And then the following message in my terminal:

```
Error: Error parsing C:/dev/temp/contracts/Migrations.sol: Command failed: tronbox --download-compiler 0.4.25
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:575:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:612:13)
    at getWrapper (C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tronbox\build\components\TronSolc.js:1:1717)
    at Object.parseImports (C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tronbox\build\components\Compile\parser.js:1:2345)
    at C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tronbox\build\components\Compile\profiler.js:1:4981
    at C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tronbox\build\components\Resolver\index.js:1:1727
    at C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tronbox\node_modules\async\internal\onlyOnce.js:12:16
    at next (C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tronbox\node_modules\async\whilst.js:68:18)
    at C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tronbox\build\components\Resolver\index.js:1:1495
    at C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tronbox\build\components\Resolver\fs.js:1:1685
```

I added this line to the top of my `tronbox.js` file:
`console.log('Running tronbox compile')`;
and noticed that once compiling the output is written twice on my screen:

[image]

I'm not sure it relates but for some reason, it runs twice.

Any idea? Is this a tronbox issue?

```
const port = process.env.HOST_PORT || 9090

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    mainnet: {
      // Don't put your private key here:
      privateKey: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_MAINNET,
      /*
Create a .env file (it must be gitignored) containing something like

  export PRIVATE_KEY_MAINNET=4E7FECCB71207B867C495B51A9758B104B1D4422088A87F4978BE64636656243

Then, run the migration with:

  source .env && tronbox migrate --network mainnet

*/
      userFeePercentage: 100,
      feeLimit: 1e8,
      fullHost: 'https://api.trongrid.io',
      network_id: '1'
    },
    shasta: {
      privateKey: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_SHASTA,
      userFeePercentage: 50,
      feeLimit: 1e8,
      fullHost: 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io',
      network_id: '2'
    },
    nile: {
      privateKey: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_NILE,
      fullNode: 'https://httpapi.nileex.io/wallet',
      solidityNode: 'https://httpapi.nileex.io/walletsolidity',
      eventServer: 'https://eventtest.nileex.io',
      network_id: '3'
    },
    development: {
      // For trontools/quickstart docker image
      privateKey: 'da146374a75310b9666e834ee4ad0866d6f4035967bfc76217c5a495fff9f0d0',
      userFeePercentage: 0,
      feeLimit: 1e8,
      fullHost: 'http://127.0.0.1:' + port,
      network_id: '9'
    },
    compilers: {
      solc: {
         version: '0.4.25'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a regression bug in tronbox 2.7.4 and 2.7.5 since when I use tronbox 2.5.2 everything works smoothly.